# Using Pandas .corr against weekday strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which I randomly generated with 100 days and random values. I've set all of the values to 500 when the day = Monday. I'm trying to run the correlate function against the days but I'm not really having any luck. I searched on stackoverflow and found some solutions but some of them weren't appropriate, and the ones which were kind of appropriate I was unable to figure out.

Here's a paste of the table just so you can see what I'm working with:

```
   Val        Day
0   21   Thursday
1   19     Friday
2    3   Saturday
3   64     Sunday
4  500     Monday
5   56    Tuesday
6   62  Wednesday
7   69   Thursday
8   43     Friday
9   34   Saturday
```

Running df.corr() returns this:

```
     Val
Val  1.0
```

I've also tried just having the days as their day index but that doesn't return a helpful output either (i.e. Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, ...)

Thanks :)

edit:

Just to make it clear, I changed the Monday value to 500 so it will become super apparent when the correlate function is working. I intend on using this to analyse spending habits against the day, but I'm just trying to get it working with dummy data first.

Comment: What is the problem with correlation. It is giving you a correlation coefficient of `Val` against `Val` which is one. If you convert the days to number and do a correlation you will get the days against value correlation. something like `label, level = pd.factorize(df['day'])` then `df['label'] = label` then `df.corr()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the days into unique numbers and do a correlation against those numbers to get the correlation for value against days.

```
label, level = pd.factorize(df['day'])
df['label'] = label
df.corr()
```

This gave me

```
    val label
val 1.00000 0.32611
label   0.32611 1.00000
```

Here is the dataframe i used

```
val day
0   21  Thursday
1   19  Friday
2   3   Saturday
3   64  Sunday
4   500 Monday
5   56  Tuesday
6   62  Wednesday
7   69  Thursday
8   43  Friday
9   34  Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

correlation function will calculate only against numeric values, try encoding weekdays and then try df.corr()